# Why can i not use exec() with the "return" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am aware this is terrible practice but i tried to run this

```
def b():
    return 'return "Foo"'


def a():
    exec(b())


print(a())
```

and got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

if i replace 'return "Foo"' with any other valid python expression it runs successfully

from my point of view,  the 'return "Foo"' is bring run from within a() and python should print "Foo", whats going on here?

----- edit -----

To ease confusion, this also gets the same error

```
def a():
    exec('return "Foo"')

print(a())
```

Comment: "from my point of view, the 'return "Foo"' is bring run from within a() and python should print "Foo", whats going on here?" That isn't how `exec` works. In any case, you **almost certainly** shouldn't be using `exec` to begin with.

Comment: Note, this is addressed explicitly in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): "In all cases, the code that’s executed is expected to be valid as file input (see the section “File input” in the Reference Manual). Be aware that the return and yield statements may not be used outside of function definitions even within the context of code passed to the exec() function. "

Comment: The code probably wants to do: `def b(): return "Foo"` and `def a(): return b()` instead.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Good Find! i missed that part in the docs.  I'm going to have to find other ways to write terrible code

Comment: @Mr_Nitrogen `exec` doesn't work like macro expansion. You aren't simply dropping a `return` statement into your function; `exec` needs something self-contained to compile, and a `return` statement isn't self-contained.

Comment: @chepner Oh ok, so its an independent code block, but executed within the current scope, weird